# iTextSharp upgrade to iText7 .NET

Tags: c#, itext

This is my iText5 code that does what I have previously required done with HTML snippets;

```
//GetFieldPositions returns an array of field positions if you are using 5.0 or greater
rectangle = pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(field.Key)[0].position;

//tell itextSharp to overlay this content 
PdfContentByte contentBtye = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);

var elements = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(pdfPlaceHolderData[key].ToString(), null);

ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(contentBtye);

ct.SetSimpleColumn(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Right, rectangle.Top);

ct.Add(elements);

ct.Go(false);

pdfFormFields.SetField(field.Key, string.Empty);
```

I am struggling to see how to convert this to work in iText7 .NET.

XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList returns 'ElementList' which inherits 'List'. 'IElement' is structured as follows;

[image: iTextSharp IElement]

The iText7 Html2Pdf call to HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(html) returns an 'IList'. However 'IElement' is now structured as follows;

[image: iText7 IElement]

I was hoping that I could of just used this result but obviously my call to 'ct.Add(elements);' in the above code chokes because of the different IElement structure.

I know I am trying to cut corners here (I have no choice at the moment); is there a relatively easy way to convert the iText7 IElement to the iTextSharp IElement that will retain my nicely parsed HTML with images?

How can I replace an acro form field content with parsed HTML instead? This would preferably be in iTextSharp 5, but I suppose would be even better using the latest version?

I currently have a solution working happily with iTextSharp 5 that allows PDF templates to populated dynamically. I have hit a problem using the `XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList` as it does not seem to support parsing inline images.

I have found that iText7 for .net has an extension called `html2pdf` that has a method called `HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements` that does perfectly parse HTML with inline images however the result is not compatible with my iTextSharp 5 implementation and I am struggling in trying to convert it.

Comment: How's it failing in iTextSharp 7?

Comment: You probably should move the last paragraph of your question up to the front as that appears to be your actual problem.

Comment: orhtej2 - thank you for your response, I have added more detail of the issue I have to the post. mkl I have edited my post as per your suggestion.

Comment: I just came back to your question to think of some solution but I now see that it is not clear what you really want. On one hand your want to know *"how to convert this to work in iText7 .NET"* but on the other hand you say it *"would preferably be in iTextSharp 5"*. So where are you heading? Obviously, though, it hardly makes any sense to try and use the pdfHTML of iText 7 for iText 5 document manipulation.

Comment: mkl - you are correct, it is not exactly clear. My problem is I have inherited a full project that is built on iTextSharp5 and this is where my problem is. Everything works as required EXCEPT when there is HTML that has inline images as XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList does not parse these images at all. I stumbled on iText7's html2pdf does parse the HTML perfectly. I am not in a position where I can confidently argue for a rewrite to use iText 7 so was desperately hoping to be able to get this HTML to parse correctly using iTextSharp, and that is where I am stuck!